# Deleted the files in /private/etc/apache2/other/

Tags: mac, macos, apache

I deleted files in `/private/etc/apache2/other/` by mistake.  Then I tried to copy files from `/private/etc/apache2/original/extra` to `/private/etc/apache2/other/` to recover my httpd, but it failed.

Now I get the error message from apache:

> "You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is
>   either no index document or the directory is read-protected. You don't
>   have permission to access the requested object. It is either
>   read-protected or not readable by the server."

So, there are two questions:

1. Can anyone can tell me what files in the "other" folder. How to produce these files.
2. How can I fix the 403 error without reproduce the files in "other" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file that is in your `/private/etc/apache2/other` directory is your php5.conf file.

What's in your `/private/etc/apache2/original/extra` directory are *sample httpd conf files* to configure your apache server.

I have made my untouched `php5.conf` file available for [download](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmW50NkbWLGikuRWeTsWx6WS01ULYA).  Since I don't use the AMP stack on my Mac for any dev work, it should be the same one that gets installed with macOS.  *It won't have any of the modifications/customizations yours had, if you made any.*

Copy that file to the 'other' directory.  Make sure you se the correct owner and  permissions:

```
sudo chmod 444 /private/etc/apache2/other/php5.conf
sudo chown root:wheel /private/etc/apache2/other/php5.conf
```